How to handle multiple SCD2 rows out-of-order with SQL
I am looking for a solution on how to handle rows that should be placed in a SCD2 table. In DLT (Delta Live Tables) this is easily solved by using  apply_changes with sequence_by and primary key parameters set. Now I am looking for a solution (either in code or a general idea) in pure T-SQL.
SCD2 is quite easy to handle when the source row always arrive in the right order. When it does not, and we add on the complexity of multiple source rows in one batch, things get hard.
For SCD2 I am currently using merge which is perfect for comparing two rows, one for source and one for target.
One solution would be to dedupe source and let the latest row take precedence - ultimately “loosing” some history. But I would like to be able to have, say, 5 rows with the same business key in source, arriving out of order, and to be able to load them in with the correct sequencing on effective dates.
How would you approach this? What does Kimball teach us on this matter?

Hi - when you say records are arriving out of order, are they still all going to be processed in the same batch? Would you ever have a record coming from your source that is earlier than the latest record in your target with the same BK?

Exactly, the same batch. A specific scenario would be a complete rerun of all historical loads from a transient staging area. So I would have a current row in target which is the actual row, and then I am backfilling "old" rows from source, and I would like to sequence by some column like "created_timestamp".

I would build all the records you want in your target in a staging table first and then you just insert them into your target, then you just need to update the current record in your target. Generating the required records would be relatively straightforward using lead/lag functions to calculate the SCD2 effective dates

Agreed. That is a completely valid approach!
